# pandas groupby using a column of list values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Given a pandas DataFrame with a column containing `list` values:

```
Month   Col2
01      ['a', 'b']
01      ['b']
01      ['a', 'c']
02      ['b', 'c']
```

**How can I perform a `groupby` based on the elements of the list in a column?**

The resulting `.groupby(['Month', 'Col2']).size()` would produce:

```
Month    Col2   size 
01       'a'    2
01       'b'    2
01       'c'    1
02       'b'    1
02       'c'    1
```

Note: the `Col2` values were "unpacked" for grouping...

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can using `explode` after `pandas` 0.25.0

```
df.explode('Col2').groupby(['Month','Col2']).size()
```

Comment: This `explode` is pretty convenient, but I'm stuck with 0.24.2 for a while :-(.

Comment: @QuangHoang if that is case , you can check unnest :-)

Comment: @QuangHoang you can add the source code to your own pandas lib if you are brave :D

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
df.explode('Col2').groupby(['Month','Col2']).size().reset_index(name='size')


  Month Col2   size
0    01    a      2
1    01    b      2
2    01    c      1
3    02    b      1
4    02    c      1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another slightly more verbose way (for people with <0.25.0 pandas like myself) you can do it is to unpack your column of list with df.itertuples() and then groupby:

```
data = [[i[1], col2] for i in df.itertuples() for col2 in i[2]]
df_data = pd.DataFrame(data = data, columns = df.columns).groupby(['Month', 'Col2']).size().reset_index(name='size')
print(df_data)
```

output:

```
  Month Col2  size
0    01    a     2
1    01    b     2
2    01    c     1
3    02    b     1
4    02    c     1
```

Comment: @QuangHoang see this for <0.25.0